# View рисуется до конца страницы

Tags: android

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 210,Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    visualizerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    visualizerLayout.addView(eq);
```

Отрисовывается до самого низа страницы, при этом оказывается под элементами, которые ниже layout в котором рисуется.

210 - это величина, которую должно занимать вью, если я правильно понимаю (рассчитано из размера вложенных во вью элементов).

`Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL` если я правильно понимаю, должен как раз настроить элементы внутри layout таким образом, чтобы они стремились занять центральное положение.

Как сделать так, чтобы eq view рисовалось по середине страницы?

Comment: а что за 210 ? Да и 3й параметр в конструкторе это weight, что вы имели ввиду написав там Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL?

Comment: А в чем вопрос то? Просто я раз 5 перечитал и не совсем понял, под какими элементами оказывается?

Comment: расскажи подробнее:
- где находится visualizerLayout;
- что именно нужно: расположить visualizerLayout в центре экрана или eq в центре visualizerLayout.

Comment: хотим пример того, как есть,  того как вам надо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinearLayout раскидывает виджеты в стек(горизонтальный или вертикальный).
для центрирования проще использовать RelativeLayout. а центрирование задать правилом

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT); // или CENTER_VERTICAL.
```

и LayoutParams в таком случае применять нужно не для самого лейаута, а для View eq.